# Power analysis with R

Tags: r, statistical-power

I have two questions regarding the R script.

If I want to know the size of the sampling when I do a t-test with R, I can use this R script :

```
power.t.test(delta=1,sd=1.5,sig.level=0.05,power=0.8)
```

If I want to know the size of the sampling when I do the test of Pearson correlation coefficient, what is the R script?

And for a chi-square test what is the R script?

Comment: You can look at the pwr package for one approach to these problems.

Comment: The question could be migrated to SO, it has already received a full answer anyway.

Answer (score 7):

For correlation:

```
pwr.r.test(n = , r = , sig.level = , power = )
```

and for chi-square

```
pwr.chisq.test(w =, N = , df = , sig.level =, power = )
```

For others, see [here](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html)