# Free internet or downloadable resources for sample size calculations

Tags: statistical-power

Today I noticed [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63364/power-analysis-with-r), and I thought it would be helpful if we had a thread that listed resources that people could conveniently access for power analysis / sample size calculations, perhaps analogous to this thread: [Resources for learning R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Power analysis](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/power-analysis/) refers to analytical procedures that attempt to determine the [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) of a statistical test (i.e., the probability of rejecting a false null hypothesis) or the sample size (i.e., $N$) required to achieve a given power.  You can search Cross Validated for more information about power analysis by clicking here: [power-analysis](/questions/tagged/power-analysis), here: [power](/questions/tagged/power), or possibly here [sample-size](/questions/tagged/sample-size).

**Free software for power analyses:**

- [G*Power](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/abteilungen/aap/gpower3/)
- [PS: Power and sample size calculator](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/PowerSampleSize)
- [Optimal Design software](http://sitemaker.umich.edu/group-based/home) - statistical power analysis for multi-level and longitudinal research

**Websites with free sample size calculators:**

- [Russ Lenth](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/%7Erlenth/Power/) has a java-based web app
- [Michael Friendly](http://www.math.yorku.ca/SCS/Online/power/) has a power analysis / sample size calculator for ANOVA designs
- [Rollin Brant's webpage](http://www.stat.ubc.ca/%7Erollin/stats/ssize/b2.html) for comparing two proportions
- [OpenEpi](http://www.openepi.com/) has sample size/power calculators for basic epidemiological study designs.
- [webpower](https://webpower.psychstat.org/wiki/) a web based interface for power analyses (based on the package listed below) for people who don't use R

**Open source programming languages with power analysis libraries / modules:**

- [R](http://www.r-project.org/) packages:

  - [pwr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/index.html) is the oldest power-analysis library; some introductory info can be found on [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html)
  - [PoweR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PoweR/): Computation of power and level tables for hypothesis tests
  - [Power2Stage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Power2Stage/index.html): Power and Sample size distribution of 2-stage BE studies via simulations
  - [powerAnalysis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerAnalysis/): Power analysis in experimental design
  - [powerGWASinteraction](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerGWASinteraction/index.html): Power Calculations for Interactions for GWAS
  - [powerMediation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerMediation/index.html): Power/Sample size calculation for mediation analysis, simple linear regression, logistic regression, or longitudinal study
  - [powerpkg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerpkg/index.html): Power analyses for the affected sib pair and the TDT design
  - [powerSurvEpi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerSurvEpi/index.html): Power and sample size calculation for survival analysis of epidemiological studies
  - [PowerTOST](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PowerTOST/index.html): Power and Sample size based on two one-sided t-tests (TOST) for (bio)equivalence studies
  - [longpower](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/longpower/): Power and sample size for linear model of longitudinal data
  - [webpower](https://cran.r-project.org/package=WebPower): "a collection of tools for conducting both basic and advanced statistical power analysis" (also a website)
- There is a [Python](https://www.python.org/) module, [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/), that can run some power analyses.  There is some information [here](http://jpktd.blogspot.com/2013/03/statistical-power-in-statsmodels.html).

Comment: Anyone who is aware of a freely available resource that is not listed already is encouraged to edit this to include that information.