# Determine Number of observations required

Tags: mathematical-statistics

How to determine whether the number of data required to be taken for a experiment?

eg: I need to take a set of data for the noise mapping, how many should I take ?

Comment: See this question for more resources you can use to calculate the required sample size: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63391/free-internet-or-downloadable-resources-for-sample-size-calculations/63392

Answer (score 2):

This is connected to [power analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power), that enables you to [estimate a desirable sample size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination) for analysis. There are different methods for different statistical tests, [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/t_test_power2.htm) you can find a tutorial on using [pwr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/) R package for t-test. In [Spiegelhalters et al. book](http://books.google.pl/books?id=eZdRL53PuWsC&dq=Bayesian%20Approaches%20to%20Clinical%20Trials%20and%20Health-Care%20Evaluation) you can find examples of dealing with this kind of problems in Bayesian fashion.